# What is the diferent about data that defined inside the state and outside state that create inside the constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

can you explain me the diferent about the data inside state and outside state like this :

```
constructor(){
this.data1 = "this is data 1", 
this.state = {
this.data2 = "this is data 2"}
}
```

So if I use data 2 inside the componentDidMount or in render function without any conditional code it will throws error that describe React cannot allow the infinite loop bla bla bla, but if I use  data1 in the componentDidMount or in render function, it works perfectly. So what is the difernet is ? Should I use data1 to make my self get more flexibility ?

Comment: Well firstly that's not even valid Javascript. But anyways, the difference between the two is that data inside the state is data that's related to the rendering of your component. If the data is static, or doesn't require a re-render when it changes, you can define it outside the state as an instance variable (like you did with `data1`). If changing it should trigger a re-render, then you should store it inside your state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This is a valid syntax

   ```
   constructor(){
      this.data = "this is data 1"; 
   }
   ```
2. This is not a valid syntax

   ```
   constructor(){
     this.state = {
       this.data = "this is data 2"
     } 
   }
   ```
3. However, this is valid

   ```
   constructor(){
      this.state = {
        data: "this is data 2"
     } 
   }
   ```

So here is what is the difference.

1 is valid but on changing the value like `this.data = 'Some new value'` will not trigger component render and if you are showing this value in your jsx/html, that will not reflect the updated value unless some other state change triggers the render function.

3 is the way to define a state variable and you should never `mutate` or directly update the state like `this.state.data = 'some value'`. You need to update value like `this.setState({ data: 'some new value' })` which will trigger render function

Comment: ty master for the explanation

Comment: is what you mean this.data1 = "some new value" instead of this.data2 = "some new value" from your first explanation ?

Comment: @argawirawan no no, it's same. I just updated all to `this.data`

Comment: Great very well